# Spark Memory Management for OOM

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Here is the case: I launch a spark job, but failed due to many tasks failed for the OOM. So I increase the memory allocation for tasks. I still see some nodes failed for OOM, but the job could succeed at last. My question is how does Spark handle this? It seems that Spark could redistribute the data after a failed try. 
P.S. The failed task is apply a `Window and Rank` operation in the batch job.

Update:
I run the batch job in YARN cluster mode. All tasks are configured to have the same memory.

Comment: Do all nodes have the same amount of memory? Are you using YARN or Standalone?

Comment: @cricket_007 All nodes have the same memory. And I run the job in YARN cluster mode.

Comment: You can increase executor memory, but you're still limited by yarn container sizes and all other processes consuming memory on any given machine

Comment: @cricket_007 The memory is within the limitation of yarn container size. My curiosity is in the same job run, some task can succeed on some executor but failed on other executors

Comment: As I said, you need to account for the non-Spark applications running on the other machines in the cluster

Answer (score 0):

Spark **DAGScheduler** builds stages of task and submit task to **TaskScheduler** to run the task. TaskScheduler launch the task on executors and re-run the failed task into different executors and reports to **DAGScheduler**. You can control the number times, task to be retried before it give up is spark.task.maxFailures. The default value is 4.

[spark config](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

Please use repartitions or increase the executor memory in-order to avoid re-run the task.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know the retry of failed tasks in Spark. What confused me is, for example, task `A` failed on executor `E1`, but later when `A` is scheduled again, it could succeed on another executor, even though all executors are configured with the same memory.

Comment: David,  There might be data shuffling is less, could you please check the data locality level of task. The one which failed might be need data shuffling from another node and  succeed task might be running in the same node where partitions resides.

Comment: I checked failed tasks, the locality level are all `PROCESS_LOCAL`

Answer (score 0):

Spark definitely retry failed tasks on some other executors, but with a limited and configured times at most. If you encounter over 10 or 20 percent OOM of tasks, that really means you allocated too few memory or each partition contains too much data to process. For the later cause, you need to distribute data into smaller partition.